# Applications of GIS in geomorphology

Tags: geosciences

I'm taking a geomorphology class right now that is theoretical, learning about geomorphic processes and formations.  There is no computer or quantitative component.

I'm enjoying it as far as it goes, but I'm left wondering: what does GIS get used for in modern geomorphology.  What kind of data gets collected?  What do people do with the data?

Comment: Have you done any investigation of any kind on this, such as Googling [geomorphology GIS](https://www.google.com/search?q=geomorphology+GIS)?  (I get loads of useful hits with that.)

Comment: Oh.  I especially like the second result I see, "APPLICATIONS OF GIS IN GEOMORPHOLOGY."  Thanks, @whuber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Coastal management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastal_management) and coastline delineation using [photogrammetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry) and [LiDAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar) seem to be popular topics.

Answer (score 5):

I just graduated with a masters in geography and my focus was in Geomorphology. :)

I was at the cutting edge of ultra-high (1cm) resolution terrain modeling.  We used Terrestrial laser scanners to generate almost perfect representations of the ground before and after geomorphic events (think rain eroding soil, or waves eroding beach dunes).

If you want more information check out my website ThadWester.com, it has a TON of examples.  Shoot me an email if you want anymore information, I would be glad to share pictures/information.

-Thad

Answer (score -1):

discuss the contribution of rivers to landscape development